# mail.log equivalent in php<5.3

Tags: php, email

I wanted to know that is there any script or tool available which can do the same task what
[mail.log](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.mail.log) does in php5.3
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of a tool that would do the [equivalent of what `mail.log` does in PHP](http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_TRUNK/ext/standard/mail.c#204). Your two best bets IMO are [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace) and [strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace). Both do much more than what you are looking for though.

An alternative would be to wrap the call to `mail()` in your own function and then use that instead of the native function in your application, which is probably the most sane solution if you are just after having a mail log.

Yet another alternative would be to [rename the function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-rename.php) with [runkit](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.runkit.php) and then [redefine `mail()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-redefine.php) to call the renamed function. But runkit is runkit, e.g. you dont want that in your production code.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, But I have a problem that server hosts more than 25 sites and it is not possible for us to debug each of the mail function. Is there any centralized way to find the spamming.

Comment: @Irfan well, you could upgrade to PHP 5.3+. After all, PHP 5.2 has reached End of Life for quite some time now. However, there should also be a log for sendmail (which is what PHP's mail function uses) in your server's log file directly, e.g. /var/log/mail or something.

Comment: I think this is only the valid answer for this question.Thanks for your time.